# Python DateTime converting list of datetime inputs to only date format

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am getting a big list of objects in this format:

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 13, 59, 45, 624362, tzinfo=<UTC>), ... ]
```

I would like for each date in this list to be converted to a string looking like this:

```
['2020-03-05', ...]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[dt.date().isoformat() for dt in your_list_of_datetimes]`

Comment: Thank you, it worked.. can only accept your answer in 10 mins.. will do, have a good one